# How to adjust tabulator width so that for all browser zoom it should adjust properly

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript, tabulator

```html
<div id="wormGearTabulatorTable" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%; position: relative;" class="tabulator" role="grid" tabulator-layout="fitDataTable"><div class="tabulator-header" role="rowgroup"><div class="tabulator-header-contents" role="rowgroup"><div class="tabulator-headers" role="row" style="height: 62px;"><div class="tabulator-col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="name" style="min-width: 40px; width: 78px; height: 62px;"><div class="tabulator-col-content"><div class="tabulator-col-title-holder"><div class="tabulator-col-title" style="text-align: left;">Type</div></div></div></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle" style="height: 62px;"></span><div class="tabulator-col tabulator-col-group" role="columngroup" aria-sort="none" aria-title="Value" style="height: 62px;"><div class="tabulator-col-content" style="max-width: 119px;"><div class="tabulator-col-title-holder"><div class="tabulator-col-title" style="text-align: center;">Value</div></div></div><div class="tabulator-col-group-cols" style="min-height: 42px;"><div class="tabulator-col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="minValue" style="min-width: 40px; width: 40px; height: 41px;"><div class="tabulator-col-content"><div class="tabulator-col-title-holder"><div class="tabulator-col-title" style="text-align: right;">Min</div></div></div></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle" style="height: 41px;"></span><div class="tabulator-col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="nomValue" style="min-width: 40px; width: 40px; height: 41px;"><div class="tabulator-col-content"><div class="tabulator-col-title-holder"><div class="tabulator-col-title" style="text-align: right;">Nom</div></div></div></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle" style="height: 41px;"></span><div class="tabulator-col" role="columnheader" aria-sort="none" tabulator-field="maxValue" style="min-width: 40px; width: 40px; height: 41px;"><div class="tabulator-col-content"><div class="tabulator-col-title-holder"><div class="tabulator-col-title" style="text-align: right;">Max</div></div></div></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle" style="height: 41px;"></span></div></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle" style="height: 62px;"></span></div><div class="tabulator-frozen-rows-holder" style="min-width: 0px;"></div></div></div><div class="tabulator-tableholder" tabindex="0" style="height: 260px;"><div class="tabulator-table" role="rowgroup" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;"><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-odd" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Axial Damping [N*S/mm]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-even" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Axial Stiffness [kN/mm]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-odd" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Efficiency [-]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.83</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.83</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.83</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-even" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Inertia Worm Wheel [kgmm²]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-odd" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Inertia Worm [kgmm²]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-even" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Max. Motor Torque [Nm]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">0.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div><div class="tabulator-row tabulator-selectable tabulator-row-odd" role="row"><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="name" style="width: 78px; text-align: left; height: 35px;">Transmission Worm -  Worm Wheel [-]</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="minValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell tabulator-editable" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="nomValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px;">21.00</div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span><div class="tabulator-cell" role="gridcell" tabulator-field="maxValue" tabindex="0" style="width: 40px; text-align: right; height: 35px; background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);"></div><span class="tabulator-col-resize-handle"></span></div></div></div></div>
```

[first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGpBf.jpg)
[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Jwp.jpg)

my table width should adjust to all zooms so that it should look proper like second image attached

```js
[enter image description here][1]

     this.iShaftTabulatorHeaders = [
                {
                    title: "Type", field: "name", headerHozAlign: "left", width: "42%", headerSort: false, hozAlign: "left", editable: false
    
                },
                {
                    title: "Value", headerHozAlign: "center", width: "60%",
                    columns: [
                        {
                            title: "Min", field: "minValue", editor: "input",editable:editCheck, headerSort: false, width: "20%", hozAlign: "right", formatter:
                                decimalFormatter
                            , headerHozAlign: "right", cellEdited: validateIShaft
                            , editorParams: {
                                formatter: decimalFormatter
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Nom", field: "nomValue", editor: "input", headerSort: false, cellEdited: validateIShaft, width: "20%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"
    
                            , editorParams: {
                                formatter: decimalFormatter
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Max", field: "maxValue", editor: "input",editable:editCheck, cellEdited: validateIShaft, headerSort: false, width: "20%", hozAlign: "right", formatter: decimalFormatter, headerHozAlign: "right"
    
                            , editorParams: {
                                formatter: decimalFormatter
                            }
                        },
                    ],
                },
    
            ];
            this.ishaftTabulatorTable = new Tabulator("#ishaftTabulatorTable", {
                maxHeight: "100%",
                maxWidth: "100%",
                data: ishaftTableData,
                layout: "fitDataTable",
                headerSort: false,
                columns: this.iShaftTabulatorHeaders,
            })

[it is coming like this for my code ][1]
 [i want like this it should adjust for zooms][1]
```

```html
                                <div *ngIf="tableDataWorm!==null||tableDataWorm !== undefined||tableDataWorm.length !==0"  id="ishaftTabulatorTable" style="max-height: 100%;max-width: 100%;position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: `like second image attached` what image?

Comment: attached check in post it should adjust for all zooms but for me it is coming like first image last column max and its data are going inside of that scroll and i need to drag scroll to see properly tried it width adjustment's but not coming properly

Comment: @jaromanda X can u check this

Comment: oh, there it is - no idea, something to do with html and css but there is none

Comment: @Timur can  u please help this

Comment: You have added style 42% in title: "Type", can you please check with 40%, because you already set 60% width to title: "Value".

Comment: Hi @Jignesh Panchal i tried by adding 40% and if i give exact 40 % then table is shrinking and not showing completing while loading first time

Comment: Okay, can you please add the table's HTML code after the render code from the using inspect from browser?

Comment: It's hard to find out, without seen real data, can you please share object value which you are getting in ishaftTableData?

Comment: You can try `layout: 'fitColumns'` instead of `fitDataTable`

Answer (score 0):

You have to write media queries as custom css. You have to find relation between zoom level and pixel width.So if you tailor your website for various devices through the use of media queries, ensuring responsiveness, the browser zoom level is automatically considered.